# powershell GCI recursively skipping folders and certain file types

Tags: powershell, directory, file-extension, get-childitem

Currently I am using this line to collect all files in a certain path (and beyond)

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $loc -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer }
```

however now ive been asking to generate this list while exclude (for example) all "docx" and "xlsx" files... and folders named "scripts" and their content

I want to read in these file extensions and directory names from a txt file into an array and simply use that array.

Also would speed is important as the functions I will be performing on these files take long enough, I dont need this process slowing down my script 10 full (a bit is okay)

Thanks so much for any inputs

FAILED ATTEMPT:

```
gi -path H:\* -exclude $xfolders | gci -recurse -exclude $xfiles | where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }
```

I think this works but only does the folder exclusion at the root of the H:\ drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? I'm comparing the realative path only(path from $loc) in case `$loc` includes one of the foldernames to ignore.

```
$loc = "C:\tools\scripts\myscripts\"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $loc -Recurse -Exclude *.docx, *.xlsx | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer -and !($_.FullName.Replace($loc,"") -like "*scripts\*") }
```

Multiple folders(this got ugly):

```
#Don't include "\" at the end of $loc - it will stop the script from matching first-level subfolders
$loc = "C:\tools\scripts\myscripts"
$ignore = @("testfolder1","testfolder2");

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $loc -Recurse -Exclude *.docx, *.xlsx | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { $relative = $_.FullName.Replace($loc,""); $nomatch = $true; foreach ($folder in $ignore) { if($relative -like "*\$folder\*") { $nomatch = $false } }; if ($nomatch) { $_ } }
```

Comment: that is beautiful ... works perfect.... I would like to supply multiple folder names and file extentions with arrays though ... for the files "-exclude $array" should workd fine, however how can I do that for the folder exclusion?

Comment: how are you going to specify the folders? fullpathname (ex. 'c:\tools\scripts\myscripts\test\...') or just a random foldername (ex. 'test') ?

Comment: user supplied via a text file, one foldername per line... so yes for example exclude all folders named "test" and "documents" ... not full path

Comment: updated answer now. I think someone can simplify it, but it seems to work at least.

Comment: wow... not the most elegant but it does work... im concerned about its speed... gonna take it for a test spin

Comment: nope, not very elegant. I tried splitting the relative path into an array and comparing it with the ignore-array, but that was slower in my small test. It may be different if you got a large number to test. let me know if you'd want that version. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you're headed down the right path. To exclude *.docx files and *.xlsx files, you'll want to supply them to the -exclude parm as an array of filter strings.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $loc -Recurse -Exclude @('*.docx','*.xlsx') | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer }
```

Comment: that works for files... but I need to exclude folders and their content

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this as well, and [Graimer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702944/graimer)'s answer didn't work (way too complex as well), so I've come up with the following.

```
$ignore = @("*testfolder1*","*testfolder2*");
$directories = gci $loc -Exclude $ignore | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -desc
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 3 of PowerShell, we can tell Get-ChildItem to show only files as follows:

```
PS> $files = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $loc
```

If you only want certain filenames (e.g. abc*.txt) to be collected, you can also use a filter:

```
PS> $files = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $loc -Filter abc*.txt
```